# ¿Es posible cambiar el color del fondo de una Actividad "Flotante"?

Tags: java, android, xml

Necesito algo parecido a `DialogFragment` pero con una clase completa, en otras palabras, crear una `activity` flotante. El procedimiento es el siguiente:

En mi `MainActivity` pulso encima de un *Item* de mi `ListView` y me muestra un *menú contextual* selecciono *Más Información* y se abre mi clase `MasInformacion` cargando los datos de mi `Sqlite` de ese *Item*, pues bien, con este código he conseguido que `MasInformacion` sea flotante (quizás no sea la mejor opción, si hay otra mejor podéis comentármelo por favor) y transparente para que muestre detrás mi `MainActivity`, así:

[image]

Pues bien, yo busco que sea así:

[image]

Que no sea completamente transparente, sino que tenga opacidad para oscurecer la ´clase´ que hay detrás.

`MasInformacion`: Así la hago "Flotante"

```
    DisplayMetrics flotante = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(flotante);

    int width = flotante.widthPixels;
    int height = flotante.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.9),(int)(height*.7));

...

// Recupero los datos de la DB

       extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
            editTextNombre.setText(extras.getString("nombre"));
            editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));
            editTextZodiaco.setText(extras.getString("zodiaco"));
            editTextEdad.setText(extras.getString("edad"));
            editTextDiasrestantes.setText(extras.getString("diasrestantes"));
            ruta_imagen = extras.getString("ruta_imagen");
            imagenPersona.setImageBitmap(crearThumb());
        }
    }
```

`MainActivity`

```
// menu contextual

   @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_contextual_mas_informacion:
                masInformacion((int)info.id);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
        }
    }

...

// metodo masInformacion

    public void masInformacion(int p_id){
            Persona persona;
            try{
                persona = baseDatos.getPersona(p_id);
                // Se dirige a la actividad MasInformacion
                Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, MasInformacion.class);

                // Carga los datos para mostrar en MasInformacion
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("id", p_id);
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("nombre", persona.getNombre());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("edad", persona.getEdad());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("diasrestantes", persona.getDiasrestantes());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("ruta_imagen", persona.getRutaImagen());
                startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (getResources().getString(R.string.error_mostrarinformacion)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                baseDatos.cerrar();
            }
        }
```

`style.xml` lo cargo desde `AndroidManifest` con `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Flotante"/>`

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Flotante">

        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/borde_flotante</item>
    </style>

   <!-- probe así pero lo transparente se vuelve completamente negro, cuando "colorPrimary" no es negro-->

    <style name="AppTheme.Flotante">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ejemplo si deseas de background un color "transparente", conteniendo un , definelo en `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

y lo mandas llamar desde el estilo definido:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Flotante">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

---

Recuerda que puedes definir otro tipo de opacidad como ejemplo un color verde :

```
#00FF00
```

A este color puedes definirle opacidad, ya sea sin opacidad:

```
#0000FF00
```

o completamente opaco:

```
#FF00FF00
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Jorgesys pero sigo igual, el color sigue siendo negro ponga el color que ponga en `transparent`

Comment: Podrías agregar la imagen por favor, no se muestra! =( por cierto ya ví lo que comentamos ayer sobre el calendario de Birthday

Comment: Se ve ahora la imagen? Estoy teniendo problemas al subirlas. Cuando estés libre abres chat y me comentas! Gracias @Jorgesys !

Comment: Ya veo que es un problema subir imagenes, creo que es un problema en amazon! : https://status.aws.amazon.com/ dame 20 minutos para comer. =)

Comment: Marco también como útil por el color opaco! Que era otra de mis dudas, gracias ! Lo de cambiar el color no funcionó pero ya utilice un `DialogFragment`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ver la documentación aquí:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Dentro del onClick() de tu item llama a este método:

```
showDialog();
```

---

From Google docs:

```
void showDialog() {
        // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
        // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
        // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = fm.findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        // Create and show the dialog.
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(ft, "tag");
    }
```

Y aquí el custom DialogFragment:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Con esto mostrarás el contenido del layout (en este caso custom_layout.xml) en una ventana flotante con fondo con la transparencia por defecto.

Si quieres enviar información a este fragment hazlo de la siguiente manera.

From Google docs:

```
static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
    MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
}
```

He probado el código, funciona y hace lo que pides.

---

Si quieres transformar la Activity que tienes al DialogFragment, usa el mismo layout, pasa el contenido del onCreate de tu Activity al onCreateView del fragment y copia todos los métodos y variables.

Comment: Copia el layout que usa esa Activity, el archivo xml mas_informacion.xml para ver la estructura de las vistas. Aún así estás cambiando el tamaño de la Activity y quieres cambiar el fondo de la aplicación, no es una práctica común y seguramente no es nada recomendado. Deberías usar un DialogFragment o otra vista para hacer esto.

Comment: Si explicas exactamente lo que quieres hacer con una imagen de muestra podría mostrarte un ejemplo mucho más específico. Detrás del fondo con transparencia ¿que quieres que se vea, contenido de otra Activity? ¿Como aparece esta pantalla, como popup o como una pantalla nueva?

Comment: Como habrás visto en la otra pregunta que borré no me funciona un `DialogFragment` ya que yo necesito una clase completa 'flotante' @MarcGV

Comment: Por favor, describe exactamente lo que quieres y pon una imagen si es posible. ¿Que quieres que se vea detrás de la transparencia, contenido, un color o imagen? El DialogFragment era para crearlo y mostrarlo encima de la Activity, no para convertir la Activity en DialogFragment

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, espero que ahora esté todo explicado correctamente, gracias @MarcGV

Comment: Fíjate que en un fragment los extras se obtienen de una manera diferente (getArguments().getInt()) por ejemplo. Puedes verlo en mi respuesta o en la documentación del link